# SuiteCRM Login ReST php. | Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\php files\loginAuth.php on line 60|

Tags: php, rest, crm, sugarcrm, suitecrm

This is the code that I pulled over from this link http://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.5/Application_Framework/Web_Services/Examples/REST/PHP/Logging_In/

```
    <?php

//$url = "http://{site_url}/service/v4_1/rest.php";
$url = "localhost/SuiteCRM-master\service\v4_1/rest.php";
$username = "arysaputra";
$password = "P@55w0rd";

//function to make cURL request
function call($method, $parameters, $url)
{
    ob_start();
    $curl_request = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_0);
    curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);

    $jsonEncodedData = json_encode($parameters);

    $post = array(
         "method" => $method,
         "input_type" => "JSON",
         "response_type" => "JSON",
         "rest_data" => $jsonEncodedData
    );

    curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
    $result = curl_exec($curl_request);
    curl_close($curl_request);

    $result = explode("\r\n\r\n", $result, 2);
    $response = json_decode($result[1]);
    ob_end_flush();

    return $response;
}

//login ------------------------------ 
$login_parameters = array(
     "user_auth" => array(
          "user_name" => $username,
          "password" => md5($password),
          "version" => "1"
     ),
     "application_name" => "RestTest",
     "name_value_list" => array(),
);

$login_result = call("login", $login_parameters, $url);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($login_result);
echo "</pre>";

//get session id
$session_id = $login_result->id;

?>
```

and when accessed, via http://localhost/php%20files/loginAuth.php I was replied with

**"Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\php files\loginAuth.php on line 60"**

Answer (score 0):

This is late, and it probably won't help you anymore, but still... The error is in `$url` where you have some backslashes mixed in, making address invalid.